# How to add a set of char[] to a List<String>?

Tags: java

I have a `List<String>` which I want to add a list of `char[]`.

I cannot change the String type of the list. My goal is to add every character in the test string as a single entry to the list.

The following does not work. What do I have to change?

```
    String test = "test";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (char c : test.toCharArray()) {
        list.add(c);
    }
```

Comment: hopefully, you are getting a compile error as the "seperators" variable is never declared.

Comment: what do you mean by list of char[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
String chars = "test";              
List<String> lst = Arrays.asList(chars.split(""));
```

Comment: Oneliner is great for my case here!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
separators.add(String.valueOf(c));
```

`separators` should be `list` right?

Answer (score 1):

Use String [valueOf(char c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%29)

```
for (char c : test.toCharArray()) {
        separators.add(String.valueOf(c));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change you code `separators.add(c);` to

```
separators.add(String.valueOf(c));
```

Your code is giving error because, you try to use char in the String place.